# list all the computer names on a local network on iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, networking

Is there any way to get and display a list of computer names(including ip address) on a local network in a tableview on iPhone. All computers include mac, windows, linux etc.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question may help you: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572697/how-to-get-domain-name-of-ipaddress-and-ipaddress-from-domain-name-in-objective>

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts to what you need to do: Sweep the local network to find all active hosts and do a reverse DNS lookup on their IP address. A brief search should show you how to do either.