# How to get the names and ips of all devices on my local network?

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos, local-network

My goal is to list the names and ips of all the devices on the local network.

[list all the computer names on a local network on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7835157/list-all-the-computer-names-on-a-local-network-on-iphone) similar to this post, but it wasn't answered.

I've looked into Apples Bonjour and don't think that's what I need. It doesn't show all the devices on network.

I've also tried the code below, but I get weird output (below).

```
int sock;
struct ifconf ifconf;
struct ifreq ifreq[30];
int interfaces;
int i;

// Create a socket or return an error.
sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (sock < 0)
    diep("socket");

// Point ifconf's ifc_buf to our array of interface ifreqs.
ifconf.ifc_buf = (char *) ifreq;

// Set ifconf's ifc_len to the length of our array of interface ifreqs.
ifconf.ifc_len = sizeof ifreq;

//  Populate ifconf.ifc_buf (ifreq) with a list of interface names and addresses.
if (ioctl(sock, SIOCGIFCONF, &ifconf) == -1)
    diep("ioctl");

// Divide the length of the interface list by the size of each entry.
// This gives us the number of interfaces on the system.
interfaces = ifconf.ifc_len / sizeof(ifreq[0]);

// Print a heading that includes the total # of interfaces.
printf("IF(%d)\tIP\n", interfaces);

// Loop through the array of interfaces, printing each one's name and IP.
for (i = 0; i < interfaces; i++) {
    char ip[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
    struct sockaddr_in *address = (struct sockaddr_in *) &ifreq[i].ifr_addr;

    // Convert the binary IP address into a readable string.
    if (!inet_ntop(AF_INET, &address->sin_addr, ip, sizeof(ip)))
        diep("inet_ntop");

    printf("FOUND: %s\t%s\n", ifreq[i].ifr_name, ip);
}

close(sock);
```

This is the output, which I can't really make sense of.

```
FOUND: lo0  24.3.0.0
FOUND:  28.30.0.0
FOUND:  0.0.0.0
FOUND:  0.0.0.0
FOUND:  0.0.0.1
FOUND: ip0  112.100.112.95
FOUND: pdp_ip1  255.7.0.0
FOUND:  20.18.4.0
FOUND: ip2  0.0.0.0
FOUND: ap1\256\372\272J\221\253 0.0.0.0
FOUND:  105.112.50.0
FOUND:  254.74.145.171
FOUND: ip2  0.0.0.0
FOUND: ip2  101.110.49.142
FOUND: awdl0    6.5.6.0
FOUND: \273Y\311    28.30.0.0
```

I'd like to see output something like this:

```
My-Mac    192.168.0.21
My-iPad   192.168.0.22
Mum's iPhone 192.168.0.23
```

A solution in either Objective-C or C++ would be useful. Thanks.

Comment: You could look at how [Nmap](http://nmap.org/) does it.

Comment: hi , I know this is a some what old post, but did you get the solution, also how does this code work for you, what all #includes do i need.

Comment: I got the above code from [here](http://blog.markloiseau.com/2012/02/get-network-interfaces-in-c/), but I ended up using [Bonjour](https://developer.apple.com/bonjour/). Not exactly what I was looking for but it ended up working for me.

Comment: @user1135469  m not able to understand using Bonjur also, it will be good if u share the code.... i want same thing to do....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just dug up this project again...and this is my attempt at sharing the code as @PRSingh requested...hope it helps.

Defined in my .h

```
 NSNetServiceBrowser *serviceBrowser;
 NSNetService *service;
 NSMutableArray* snames;
 NSMutableArray* sips;
 UIActivityIndicatorView* spinner;
```

In my .m

```
#pragma mark - NSNetServiceDelegate Methods

- (void)netServiceWillResolve:(NSNetService *)sender {
    NSLog(@"netServiceWillResolve");

    serviceBrowser = [[NSNetServiceBrowser alloc] init];
    if(!serviceBrowser) {
        NSLog(@"The NSNetServiceBrowser couldn't be allocated and initialized.");
    }
    serviceBrowser.delegate = self;
    [serviceBrowser searchForServicesOfType:@"_type._tcp." inDomain:@"local."];
}

- (void)netServiceWillPublish:(NSNetService *)netService
{
    NSLog(@"netServiceWillPublish");
}

- (void)netServiceDidPublish:(NSNetService *)sender {
    NSLog(@"netServiceDidPublish");
}

- (void)netService:(NSNetService *)sender didNotPublish:(NSDictionary *)errorDict {
    NSLog(@"didNotPublish");
}

- (void)netServiceDidResolveAddress:(NSNetService *)netService {
    NSLog(@"netServiceDidResolveAddress");
    for (NSData* data in [netService addresses]) {

        char addressBuffer[100];

        struct sockaddr_in* socketAddress = (struct sockaddr_in*) [data bytes];

        int sockFamily = socketAddress->sin_family;

        if (sockFamily == AF_INET /*|| sockFamily == AF_INET6*/) {

            const char* addressStr = inet_ntop(sockFamily,
                                               &(socketAddress->sin_addr), addressBuffer,
                                               sizeof(addressBuffer));

           // int port = ntohs(socketAddress->sin_port);

            if (addressStr){
                if(![sips containsObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",addressStr]]){
                    [snames addObject:netService.name];
                    [sips addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",addressStr]];
                    [self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                }
            }

        }

    }
}

- (void)netService:(NSNetService *)sender didNotResolve:(NSDictionary *)errorDict {
    NSLog(@"didNotResolve: %@",errorDict);
}

- (void)netService:(NSNetService *)sender didUpdateTXTRecordData:(NSData *)data {
    NSLog(@"didUpdateTXTRecordData");
}

- (void)netServiceDidStop:(NSNetService *)netService {
    NSLog(@"netServiceDidStop");
}

#pragma mark - NSNetServiceBrowserDelegate Methods

- (void)netServiceBrowser:(NSNetServiceBrowser *)netServiceBrowser didFindService:(NSNetService *)netService moreComing:(BOOL)moreServicesComing {
    NSLog(@"didFindService: %@  lenght:%d",netService.name,[netService.name length]);
    [services addObject:netService];
}


- (void)netServiceBrowser:(NSNetServiceBrowser *)netServiceBrowser didRemoveService:(NSNetService *)netService moreComing:(BOOL)moreServicesComing {
    [services removeObject:netService];
    [netService stop];
    int index = [snames indexOfObject:netService.name];
    [snames removeObjectAtIndex:index];
    [sips removeObjectAtIndex:index];
    [self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

    NSLog(@"didRemoveService");
}
```

For this to work I believe that all devices on the network need to be running bonjour with a 'type' of '_type_.tcp' (or what ever name you give it). You can play around with the type just to see what devices on your local network are already on certain service types (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1312/_index.html).