# how to get computer names in the same LAN on mac

Tags: macos, cocoa

I am currently developing a Mac app to help with some computer sharing problems(this sharing should be among PC,Mac,Android device,iOS device etc.).Therefore I need to find a way to get a list of all the computers within the LAN my Mac shares with.It's totally the same with what the OS does,but I hope this could be done through my app to provide a better experience.So is there any api I could use?Is there anybody who's got an idea or did this before?I am really appreciate that you could kindly tell me.Thanks in advance.

I have found an answer to how to get the ip to a hostname. [the answer is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572697/how-to-get-domain-name-of-ipaddress-and-ipaddress-from-domain-name-in-objective%3E)

So for the first step, how to scan the LAN to get a whole list of all the devices' ip?

Comment: Bonjour might be what you are looking for: https://developer.apple.com/bonjour/index.html

Comment: is PC also detectable with Bonjour?

Comment: I believe it would need to have Bonjour installed on it.  You should update your question to mention that you also want to detect Windows machines.

Comment: thanks trojanfoe,I have edited question to clarify what I'm intend to ask.